# Why is 'ALT + ENTER' not working on Intellij 13?

Tags: intellij-idea

The keyboard combination `ALT + ENTER` seems not to be working on IntelliJ  13 
when try to import package on the project (on Windows 10 system).

I have tried numerous times without success. Has anyone else experienced this strange behavior?

Comment: it's working for me under IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6 with windows 10